cannot import name 'AliasGenerator' from 'pydantic'
stuck at this issue, any idea on how i can rectify this?
I tried installing openbb and upgrading pydantic. however i am unable to rectify this issue. Please help me provide any suggestions. thank you very much. would really appreciate it
issue regarding alias generator

Run pip install --upgrade pydantic
